# Workflow Aborted

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am working on an Asp .net application and i am using Windows workflow foundation 4. When i terminate the workflow i want to export the reason with the following code

```
     app.Aborted = delegate(WorkflowApplicationAbortedEventArgs o)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Exception:" + o.Reason.GetType().FullName + o.Reason.Message);
            syncEvent.Set();
        };
```

But i think it doesn't works because the workflow doesnt have HttpContext. Any ideas how can i export it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to wrap the WorkflowApplication and HttpContext in the same class, for example:

```
class WorkflowAppAdapter
    {
        private HttpContext m_Context;
        private WorkflowApplication m_WorkflowApp;

        public WorkflowAppAdapter(WorkflowApplication app, HttpContext context)
        {
            m_Context = context;
            m_WorkflowApp = app;

            app.Completed =
                (e) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(m_Context.Request.Browser.Browser);

                };
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            m_WorkflowApp.Run();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HttpContext.Current is a thread static field scoped to the current thread executing the ASP.NET request while the WorkflowApplication runs the workflow and the callbacks on a background ThreadPool thread.

The fact that you want to write the error back to the response stream suggest you are working with a short running workflow here. In that case it is much easier to use a WorkflowInvoker to run the workflow as there are no background threads involved.

If you perfer the WorkflowApplication than I suggest looking into the SynchronizationContext property and setting that so most callbacks will be martialled back onto the original thread.

Comment: Hm, i didnt understand what exactly do you mean

Comment: The last one, because i have to use only WorkflowApplication

Comment: Check [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/01/07/doing-synchronous-workflow-execution-using-the-workflowapplication.aspx)  blog post for an example.